# webbrowser control is not scrollable

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, webbrowser-control

in windows mobile 6.5, i used webbrowser control to display EULA, but it is not possible to scroll and see complete eula. I don't see scroll bars, and fontsize is very large. Same eula was displayed correctly when open in browser, outside the app and able to see scroll bars.

I'm writing app in C# and device has .net 3.5 compact framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: rplusg, have you found a solution to this yet?  Was the hotfix helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this problem is addressed in this link:  [MSDN KB article 975281](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975281)

There is a hotfix mentioned that may resolve the issue for you.

You can request the fix here:  [hotfix 975281](http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=975281&kbln=en-us)

As far as I know, nothing should prevent you from decreasing the font size.